# Cloud Foundry Default Infrastructure

Tags: cloud-foundry

As a cloud-native platform, Cloud Foundry directly uses cloud-based infrastructure
so that applications running on the platform can be infrastructure unaware.

That being said, would like to understand if I deploy any application using Cloud Foundary...
What infrastructure is uses by default ? It can be anything such as Azure or AWS or OpenStack etc... ?

Does this mean if I am using Cloud Foundary - It will always be combination of Cloud Foundary + Any IAAS provider ?
where CF will work as intermediate between our application and IAAS ?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Foundry is deployed and managed via Bosh. Bosh provides an abstracted layer above the chosen infrastructure (AWS, GCP, Azure, vSphere etc), any software deployed via Bosh is therefore ignorant, for the want of a better term, of the infrastructure it's been deployed on. When you deploy an application on Cloud Foundry it is also unaware of the infrastructure it has been deployed to. That's the whole premise of Cloud Foundry, taking away any infrastructure concern for developers, so they can concentrate on application code.